# How to extract URLs from this site with xpath and scrapy using href?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm still getting the gist of xpath and how it works (have been trying to learn from w3 for a while) but I'm sort of confused how to extract this section of code from this webpage: https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2005/ (I've been looking through the source here: view-source:https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2005/). I would like to extract the URLs from lines 363 - 383.

```
<ul class="">
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_1.htm">Week 1</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_2.htm">Week 2</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_3.htm">Week 3</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_4.htm">Week 4</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_5.htm">Week 5</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_6.htm">Week 6</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_7.htm">Week 7</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_8.htm">Week 8</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_9.htm">Week 9</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_10.htm">Week 10</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_11.htm">Week 11</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_12.htm">Week 12</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_13.htm">Week 13</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_14.htm">Week 14</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_15.htm">Week 15</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_16.htm">Week 16</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_17.htm">Week 17</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_18.htm">Wild Card</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_19.htm">Divisional</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_20.htm">Conf Champ</a></li>
<li><a href="/years/2005/week_21.htm">Super Bowl</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried using `$x('//ul[@class=""]/@href')` in the . console but it doesn't really work. Could someone help me extract the href from these? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are lines 363 - 383 supposed to be? I only see `href`s differentiated by weeks...

Answer (score 1):

There are two similar ways to parse the `hrefs` there.

A shorter (but more error prone, depending on how the rest of your HTML looks like)

`x('//ul[@class=""]//a/@href')`

**Meaning:** Any "a" being a descendant (direct or not) of Any "ul" node with an empty class attribute.

A slightly longer expression, but less error prone as it is more explicit

`x('//ul[@class=""]/li/a/@href')`

**Meaning:** Any "a" node being a direct descendant of any "li" node being a direct descendant of any "ul" node with an empty class attribute.

Additionally, you can try to refer to fancier xpath functions (not supported by every framework though) such as string length (for the class attribute).

Answer (score 0):

"//" will select any descendant that matches while "/" only selects direct descendants that match. Since  is not a direct descendant of , I think you're selector should be this:

```
$x('//ul[@class=""]//@href')
```

To get just the elements where the inner text starts with "Week":

```
$x('//ul[@class=""]//a[starts-with(.,"Week")]/@href')
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment, it worked but I still have the problem that it selects all of the URL's in the page (I get 134 of them). Is there a way just to select the ones I want with the week numbers? I suppose I could just find which ones they are in the array and extract them such as with `$x('//ul[@class=""]//@href')[100]`, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way (so I can learn and become familiar with XPath).